# multiple while loop won't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop, fetch

AGENT DB TABLE

```
agent_id  agent_name company_name
--------  ----------  -----------
1         AAA           XXX
2         BBB           YYY
3         CCC           ZZZ
4         DDD           XYZ
```

DRIVER DB TABLE

```
agent_id  driver_id   driver_name
--------  ----------  -----------
2         1           EEE
2         2           FFF
2         3           GGG
1         4           HHH
3         5           III
3         6           JJJ
```

I WANT TO SHOW THE RESULT LIKE THIS

```
AGENT DETAILS    DRIVER DETAILS
------------     --------------  
 1, AAA, XXX         1 Driver           
 2, BBB, YYY         3 Drivers           
 3, CCC, ZZZ         2 Drivers
 4, DDD, XYZ         0 Driver
```

I HAVE TRIED THIS BUT I GOT THE RESULT LIKE THIS

```
AGENT DETAILS    DRIVER DETAILS
------------     --------------  
 1, AAA, XXX         1 Drivers           
 1, AAA, XXX         3 Drivers           
 1, AAA, XXX         2 Drivers
 1, AAA, XXX            -
```

I have attached sample image and code below..

[image]

I hope someone can understand my problem. Here I have to show the agent and driver details. Agent table have agent_id, agent_name, company_name. I want to fetch all records from agent table. Then I want to count the number of drivers based on agent_id.

In my driver db table I have agent_id, driver_id, driver_name. I want to fetch the number of drivers from driver table based on agent_id. This is one works fine. But, My problem is I have multiple while loops so it won't fetch properly. See my attached image. You can understand easily. In Agent Details it always fetch the same rows in all rows.

I'm sure I made a mistake in while loop. But, I don't know how do I get the proper result..

```
<?php
$sql="select * from ".TBL_AGENT."";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$CN);



while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $agentid = $row['agent_id'];
    $agentname = $row['agent_name'];
    $companyname = $row['company_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT agent_id, COUNT(driver_id) AS ".TBL_DRIVER." FROM ".TBL_DRIVER."  GROUP BY $agentid");         while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    { $noofdrivers = $rows['ta_drivers']. " DRIVERS"; echo "<br/>"; 
?>
    <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="height: 70px; width: 300px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <b>Agent Name : </b><?=$agentname?><br /><br />
            <b>Business Name : </b><?=$companyname?><br /><br />
            <b>E-mail Id : </b><?=$email?>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="height: 70px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <?php 
           echo $noofdrivers; ?>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="height: 70px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;"></td>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="height: 70px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"></td>   
    </tr>
<?php }  } ?>
```

Comment: Its better to use joined query instead of running queries in loop

Comment: can you join these above two queries

Comment: [**see fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58594/1)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid : yes its working. i don't know about join queries. post your answer i will accept your answer

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid please post that as an answer !!

Comment: @Beginner i have posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from comments here is the answer ,you can join your tables as and loop over them in php

```
SELECT a.*,
COUNT(d.driver_id) `drivers_count`
FROM AGENT a
LEFT JOIN DRIVER d USING(agent_id)
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

[*A fiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58594/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT a.agent_id, 
         a.agent_name,
         a.company_name,
         count(d.*) as count_of_drivers
    FROM agent a, driver d
   WHERE a.id_agent = d.id_agent
GROUP BY a.agent_id,
         a.agent_name,
         a.company_name
```

Comment: I think you have to group by

Answer (score 1):

Use one query with join (and don't use old-style joins with coma)

```
 SELECT agent.agent_id, agent.agent_name, agent.company_name, count(driver_id) as cnt
    FROM agent left join driver on agent.agent_id = driver.agent_id
    group by agent.agent_id
```

or you can use this

```
 SELECT agent_id, agent_name, company_name, 
    (Select count(*) FROM driver d WHERE d.agent_id = m.agent_id) AS cnt FROM agent m
```

It is understandable, but can be slower on big amounts of data

SQLfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52e28/9/0